# Выбор зарезервированного порта

Tags: c++, ip, tcp, snmp

Подскажите, какой, по вашему мнению, можно выбрать порт для планируемой системы автоматического православного IT-исповедания. Суть разработки проста. Дать возможность любым сетевым устройствам примерно раз в неделю автоматически исповедоваться поверх протокола TCP перед Главным Устройством (он назначается). Сетевые устройства должны иметь возможность быстро и оперативно покаяться в своих греховных багах, при этом не сильно нагружать сетевой трафик.

Comment: Уже всё сделано до вас https://ebatyushka.com/

Comment: Мне нужно для сетевых устройств. Желательно по бинарному протоколу.

Comment: Вопрос явно не по теме данного сайта. Я понимаю, что шутка, тогда надо вставить какой-нибудь тег (по аналогии с 1_апреля). Не знаю только какой? Рождество? НГ?

Answer (score 5):

Сетевой порт должен быть настраиваемым как на клиенте, так и на сервере.

Номера портов, используемые для конкретных специфических целей, выделяет и регистрирует IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority).

Так что если вы хотите официоза - обратитесь к ним.

Далее, можно использовать [tcpmux](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpmux) - он вообще дает возможность гнать все через единственный порт номер 1, а в качестве идентификатора сервера использует строки.

В конечном итоге, берите любое число от 1024 до 49151. Порты с номерами 49152 - 65535 могут оькрываться динамически, и вы что-то сломаете.

Полезная [вики](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_TCP_%D0%B8_UDP)

*Для исповедальни хорошо подходит syslog.*

Comment: Да, syslog хорош - но не православен. За советы - пасип, обдумаю.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, какой, по вашему мнению, можно выбрать порт для планируемой системы автоматического православного IT-исповедания.

Как на счёт `7476` — год выхода «Мечтают ли андроиды об электроовцах?» Дика по эре от сотворения мира...